# Providing power to MCU

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power

I have an ESP32 that I want to power from an external source. It's a dev board and have an USB input for programming and 5V, but moving past my prototype, I want to ditch the USB (I have a separate power supply board that will power two MCUs)

The Arduino boards have a vIN pin for this purpose. My setup works if I connect the 5V output from the Power supply board to the 5V pins of my ESP32 and to the vIN of the Arduino board.

Im just curios if this is "safe" or the right way to to it. Ive always thought of the 5V pin as 5V "out", not "in".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Applying 5 V directly to Arduino 5 V line*

Yes, it is usually "safe" in that it should not break anything.

The 5 V is neither an input nor an output. It is a **supply** and that 5 V needs to be provided by something. Normally that's the 5 V from USB. It can also be the output of a 5 V regulator which gets its power from an external 7 - 12 V supply (Vraw).

But since you simply replaced the 5 V line from USB with a different 5 V line, there is no real issue.